# How to find Outage probability for such complicated expression

Tags: probability-distributions, definite-integrals, density-function, exponential-distribution, cumulative-distribution-functions

I am trying to obtain outage probability for the given expression but not getting it clearly.

$P_o = \text{Pr}\biggl(XY \leq \frac{\gamma_t(\mu_3Z+\mu_4)}{\zeta-\frac{\gamma_t \mu_1}{Y}-\frac{\gamma_t \mu_2}{X}}\biggr)$, where $X,Y,Z$ are independent exponential random variables having CDF $F_X(x), F_Y(y), F_Z(z)$ and PDF $f_X(x), f_Y(y), f_Z(z)$ and all other things are constant.

I further wrote it as

$P_o = \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} \text{Pr}\biggl(XY \leq \frac{\gamma_t(\mu_3Z+\mu_4)}{\zeta-\frac{\gamma_t \mu_1}{Y}-\frac{\gamma_t \mu_2}{X}}\biggr)f_X(x) f_Y(y) f_Z(z)\text{d}x \text{d}y \text{d}z ?$

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Any logic to solve this problem would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I know the PDF and CDF of product of $X$ and $Y$. Can we utilize it to solve this ?

Comment: Can we say that this problem is not solvable?

Comment: Any logic to solve this problem would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Any logic to solve this problem would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Pls anybody can give some hint, it will help me in proceeding with this equation.